# Bringing files and directories back to life

Tags: shell, unix

Good Afternoon,

I am having issues with my code listed below to recover files that I deleted. I'm having this error pop up saying that my line 5 integer expression expected. I will gladly appreciate the feedback.

```
#!/bin/bash
FileP="$(grep -i "$1" $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d ":" -f1)"
FileN="$(grep -i "$1" $HOME/.restore.info | cut -d":" -f2)"
echo "FileN"
if [ $1 -eq 0 ]
then
      echo "No input detected"
     exit 1;

elif [ "$FileN" = "$1" ]
then
echo "File found sending back to original location"
    mv ~/deleted/$1 $FileP

 else
 echo "File does not exist"
 exit 2;
 fi
```

Comment: `$1` you are passing to the script must be an integer. I think you are trying to check if user has passed some input argument, you should better use `$#` to check, like `if [ $# -eq 0 ];then ....;fi`

Comment: That's fixes the issue but I'm still not able to recover the file I deleted.

Comment: please add some pretext how are you recovering the deleted files, what is stored in `FileN` and `FileP`

Comment: what is `FPath` ? , actually you should put your code in shellcheck.net

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I'm checking now.

Comment: After `shellcheck` then you can turn on the shell's minimalist debugging with `set -x` before the line of interest, and `set +x` after the line of interest. This will show you the line as it is executed with all env-vars  replaced with the values the shell has chosen (and you have provided). Good luck.

Comment: FPath is incorrect I meant to say "FileP" sorry about the incorrect typo